# Orchard CMS and app_data folder in modules

Tags: security, orchardcms

I am creating a module in which I need to certificate files to be stored in the site. In a normal website I would put them in the app_data folder. In Orchard I have created a ASP.Net App_Data folder in the module. THen I have added those two files to that directory.

How can I get those two files in code. In the normal website it would be something like this:

```
<acceptantCertificate filename="App_Data\my_private.pfx" password="something" />
```

Now in the module I have created settingspart for storing this value above. So no worries also about the password. This is stored in the database. Now what path should I give this setting in order to be able to find the file. And is the App_Data folder the correct location for these kind of files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App_Data is fine. Doing a mappath on "~/Modules/YourModuleName/App_Data/my_private.pfx" should do the trick.